# React: Nested defaultProps deep merge

Tags: reactjs

I have a `track` prop with the following definition:

```
  propTypes: {
    track: React.PropTypes.shape({
      cover: React.PropTypes.string,
      title: React.PropTypes.string,
      artist: React.PropTypes.string
    })
  }
```

I would like the track.cover to get a default value if undefined:

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      track: {
          cover: 'placeholder.png'
        }
      }
  }
```

Any chance I can do that at the view level? 
Does `getDefaultProps` does a Deep Merge?
Or do I need to handle this at the model level?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getDefaultProps` does not merge passed property values with the return value specified. If the property does not exist, React will use the object returned by `getDefaultProps` to initialize the component instance.

The code below for example produces:

```
Test Cover and
```

Code:

```js
var TrackItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var track = this.props.track;
    return (<div>{track.cover} and {track.artist}</div>);
  },
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      track: {
          artist: 'def artist'
        }
      }
  }        
});

var track = {
    cover: 'Test Cover'    
};
React.render(<TrackItem track={ track } />, mountNode);
```

Also, note that objects returned in `getDefaultProps` are shared across all instances of a component ([reference](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#getdefaultprops)).

Comment: Yup. I found this issue requiring the same feature: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2568 I'm waiting for discussion now, if you want to check that out. I think it makes sense to add the deep merge in some certain cases!

Comment: I'm not sure that the complexity of handling the variety of cases is really worth it though.

Comment: It doesn't actually sounds much complicated to me though. I think I could PR that if it gets validated.

Comment: #1) Not everyone would want/need it (and it could break existing components if not made optional), #2) The equivalent could be easily handled elsewhere in the object life-cycle, #3) Would arrays be merged (especially if the elements are objects)? #4) Would need ways to indicate a property should be `undefined`, yet not take default, #5) for large object structures, could needlessly bloat memory in lists with lots of defaults (copies), etc. Also -- how would this interact with the normal [lifecycle](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) events?

Comment: @WiredPrairie #3 is a good point, but come on... you don't name things as `defaultProps` with an implementation which does shallowMerge. This means usage of defaultProps is absolutely limited to a flat object structure. At least enforce some constraints throwing a warning if you have an object graph used for it. Geez...