# React: how do you assign default properties of object props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, a child component gets passed `position={{x: 50}}`.  How do I reassign `this.props.position` inside the child component to equal `{{x: 50, y: 0}}`

Comment: Take a look at this issue against React: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2568 and this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194997/react-nested-defaultprops-deep-merge

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using React; if you're also using ES2016 you'll be able to use Object.assign:

```
var initial = {x: 0, y: 0};
var passed = {x: 50};

var result = Object.assign({}, initial, passed);

console.log(result); // { x: 50, y: 0 }
```

Comment: Would these lines of code need to be ran before every render because a child component cannot modify it's own props?

Comment: Yes, if I understand your requirement you'll just need to assign the new values with the defaults to a local variable which can then used when rendering. Object.assign will not mutate the props.

Answer (score 0):

If you just did `this.props.position` you couldn't rely on default props to work because default props wont check for specific properties missing on the object but will check to see if the prop exists at all.

The easiest way would be to have two props: positionX & positionY

Then in your child component you can set the default props of both so if one is passed in and not the other you can fallback to a default for the other one.

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
  return {
    positionX: 50,
    positionY: 0
  };
},
```

Another option is to check if it exist wherever its being used at in the child component and manipulate it at that point with a new object that has both the Y and X values.

example with Object destructuring:

`var {x, y=50} = this.props.position`

If you anticipate x might be undefined as y be passed in then you can also give x a default value. If the x or y exist on `this.props.position` then it will overwrite the defaults

Comment: That is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: You can do with object destructuring then: 

var {x, y=50} = this.props.position

this will make y have a default of 50 and x will be equal to whatever it is in this.props.position. If y does exist then it will use that vs the default

Comment: Would work, but is there a way to actually change the value of this.props and not create a default for the structured variable?

Comment: Mutating this.props would be an anti-pattern, is there any particular reason that the parent component can't be the one handling this that way it passes down position with both x and y each time and then the child doesn't have to worry about it?

Comment: Simply for the sake of making the developer experience less tedious.  For example if I wanted to set position x and y, I'd need to pass my positionX and positionY as props as opposed to my intended goal of just passing position={{x: 123, y: 123}}