# React: how to set up JSON value in defaultProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and have been tasked with updating an existing component (a form). My task is to read a setting from JSON and show or hide an element based on that setting.

The JSON appears like:

```
"forms": {
  "enquiry": {
    "showConfirmCheckbox": "true"
  },
},
```

Using and existing component that already reads this JSON and turns it into context which is called `config`, I can use the above as such:

In my propTypes I have:

```
  static propTypes = {
    config: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }
```

And in my render function I just wrap the element in a conditional statement:

```
{config.forms.enquiry.showConfirmCheckbox &&
            <Checkbox
              etc, etc, etc
```

This works fine. However, I want to add a default for this value just in case the original JSON file is not updated correctly or is missing that entry. To that effect I added this to my defaultProps:

```
static defaultProps = {
    config: {
      forms: {
        enquiry: {
          showConfirmCheckbox: 'true',
        },
      },
    },
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

If I delete the line `'showConfirmCheckbox': 'true'`, from the JSON file the if condition still validates as false - it doesn't pick up the defaultProps value.

Would anyone know how to amend this? Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Guessing its the static keyword you use for a variable, that's not right. Maybe you meant const?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there other entries to your config, which are being passed while the `showConfirmCheckbox` isn't? The `config` prop is treated as a whole, if any object is passed, default props are not applied.

Docs [on propTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values)

Comment: Ah I think you're right! Yes, there is a lot of data in config. `config.forms.search.title` for example.

Comment: Well then, afaik, defaultProps won't help you here, I can suggest providing a default value when rendering. I am not aware of better alternatives, but you may want to investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can default **nested** props because under the hood , defaultProps are only shallow merged with **first-level** props if props are missing.
 , [click for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194997/react-nested-defaultprops-deep-merge)

However, in order to get around this, you may consider adding a few customized default logics in both lifecycle HOOK **componentWillReceiveProps** and **constructor**

And maybe the **nested** propTypes can also be helpful.

```js
propTypes: {
    configs: PropTypes.shape({
        forms: PropTypes.shape({
            enquiry: PropTypes.shape({
                showConfirmCheckbox: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
            })
        })
    })
}
```