# Issue with React PropTypes combined with defaultProps and inside an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the following React 17.0.2 example:

```
// Container.tsx

const InfoPropType = {
  legend: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.number,
};

const ContainerPropTypes = {
  config: PropTypes.shape({
    c1: PropTypes.shape(InfoPropType).isRequired,
  }),
};

type ContainerType = InferProps<typeof ContainerPropTypes>;

const ContainerDefaultProps = { config: { c1: { value: 1 } } };

const Container = (props: ContainerType & typeof ContainerDefaultProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { config: cConfig } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      {cConfig.c1.legend} has {cConfig.c1.value}
    </div>
  );
};

Container.propTypes = ContainerPropTypes;
Container.defaultProps = ContainerDefaultProps;
```

```
// App.tsx

type ConfigType = { c1: { legend: string; value?: number; } };

const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  const aConfig: ConfigType = { c1: { legend: 'l1' } };

  return (<Container config={aConfig} />);
                     ^----^ /* property with lint error */
};

export default App;
```

I get an error for `config` on the line `<Container config={aConfig} />`:

```
Type 'ConfigType' is not assignable to type 'InferPropsInner<Pick<{ c1: Validator<NonNullable<InferProps<{ legend: Validator<string>; value: Requireable<number>; }>>>; }, "c1">> & Partial<...> & { ...; }'.
  Type 'ConfigType' is not assignable to type '{ c1: { value: number; }; }'.
    The types of 'c1.value' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

The expected type comes from property 'config' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<InferPropsInner<Pick<{ config: Requireable<InferProps<{ c1: Validator<NonNullable<InferProps<{ legend: Validator<string>; value: Requireable<number>; }>>>; }>>; }, never>> & Partial<...> & { ...; }, "config"> & Pick<...> & Pick<...>, never> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>'
```

Which to me basically reads: Object `aConfig` cannot be assigned to property `config`, as the type of `aConfig` has an optional key `value`, while in the expected type the `value` key is required.

But that is not the case as in `Container.tsx` the `value` key is not required.

So how can I fix this issue using propTypes, defaultTypes and InferProps?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc0SWOABRzABUBPMJAZwBo4BvOAJIA7TEigMIYDnAC%20cbLgJhGAWhhtOZSmghCO8YZggTmGuAF4%205OHAA2SAOZIhAEwBc9Rq3YcAdPqhgIQdfYA5kAEcAV2AiFy5rOAA3FFsopA8Tb05fISiQACMxBJkKch09eABhXRgUILEsjWlLXkSKzGAHTK9m-wALFHYACjabGzQARh7JbL8OQZHDY172AEpQ8KRo2KR4xJk1krL1djgaoTqGqGyLQRFGxg4AHlOkCExz2vqhR9nmgB8ZQq%20i%20lx%20YgAIkhMCgorYYCYWnw4B0uh5%20FMMclUukPJNZITStpdKCLldflA7sNlJIOB5yRCbmYAGRwN4fMEUqEwuEIpFrDwAKQAygANXwAUXsIGc8HMAKsE1J8Exuk63VRFw1hMstKkZRsRBgUSgQjgw0SNmeLmASQBVvGvDQ2q6vimvnsTlcckG0mdrpCHpSaSQMkdzwA9Lb7Yk1hRieRGddfPq5ndk5Smj4KJmxL4XLz4YinhnvtdobDi0iypHI5Q3mCNbdWqjpiivc53HAAkEHKQcaGAPwePKFMQDuSJkHwACCYDA1MFcFFEulSFllwsirGqJVcBQgYZ6q6LZRWI7ji7Hnwtkm%20CJhrgxtN5uGzzzVLRDnMvEPJ4cORIwBeNyETJAAA8aHgQsqwROB5zACggA)

Comment: That's **not** an "ESLint error"; it's from the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: btw why proptypes while using typescript? ^^

Comment: @moonwave99 reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/54690878/1980846

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a TypeScript compiler issue as @jonrsharpe mentioned. It is related to TypeScript's type checking and type inference for default values in React components.

In your Container.tsx, you have defined ContainerDefaultProps without having a default prop value for `legend` even if that is required for `InfoPropType`.

I think this would fix the issue.

```js
// Container.tsx

const ContainerDefaultProps = { config: { c1: { legend: '', value: 1 } }};

// App.tsx

const aConfig: ConfigType = { c1: { legend: 'l1', value: 0 } };};
```

Here is something more:

In React, default prop values are typically used as a fallback when a prop is not provided or is undefined. When TypeScript infers the type of a component's prop based on the default prop value, it considers the shape of the default value.

Comment: I thought that default props are not for required values. They provide the values when a non-required prop is missing.

Comment: You can do it without `legend: ''` defaultProps but the thing is since you have `InfoPropType.isRequired` in `ContainerPropTypes`, it means that legend is a required prop within InfoPropType. That would force you to have that legend property in your defaultProps.

Comment: I think the simplest way would be get rid of that `InfoPropType` and do the validation only in `ContainerPropTypes`.

Comment: None of the above suggestions solve the issue.

Comment: Check this out. This should work fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-default-props-mn7vrw?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Your solution basically removes the InferProps and creates a type similar to the propTypes but not in the propTypes format. So two different but same things to maintain. Then why do we have all that `goodness` of propTypes and defaultTypes and InferProps?

Answer (score 0):

There is a misuse of the **defaultProps** here. See [React: Nested defaultProps deep merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194997/react-nested-defaultprops-deep-merge), react will NOT do a deep merge of the two objects. So it would be one or the other, and since one has no value (which is the default) and other has no legend (which is required) neither will work as expected.

So to make this component work properly, drop the usage of the defaultProps, and make config required, since you need it to be because **config.c1** and **config.c1.legend** are required. Then manually assign the default values of optional props in case they are not available.

```
const InfoPropType = {
  legend: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.number,
};

const ContainerPropTypes = {
  config: PropTypes.shape({
    c1: PropTypes.shape(InfoPropType).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

type ContainerType = InferProps<typeof ContainerPropTypes>;

const ContainerDefaultConfigValue =  1;

const Container = (props: ContainerType): JSX.Element => {
  const { config: cConfig } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      {cConfig.c1.legend} has {cConfig.c1.value || ContainerDefaultConfigValue}
    </div>
  );
};

Container.propTypes = ContainerPropTypes;

//App.tsx

type ConfigType = { c1: { legend: string; value?: number; } };

const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  const aConfig: ConfigType = { c1: { legend: 'l1' } };

  return (<Container config={aConfig} />);
};

export default App;
```

[Ts Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&ssl=42&ssc=20&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc0SWOABRzABUBPMJAZwBo4BvOAJIA7TEigMIYDnAC%20cbLgJhGAWhhtOZSmghCO8YZggTmGuAF4%205OHAA2SAOZIhAEwBc9Rq3YcAdPqhgIQdfYA5kAEcAV2AiFy5rOAA3FFsopA8Tb05fISiQACMxBJkKch09eABhXRgUILEsjWlLXkSKzGAHTK9m-wALFHYACjabGzQARh7JbL8OQZHDY172AEpQ8KRo2KR4xJkNsMiYuJKy9XY4GqE6hqhsi0ERRsYOAB5LpAhMa9r6oSvWbNAB8ZQq%20j%20twBYgAIkhMCgorYYDdOg4AGqpdJPOCTcG6SE3O6AqBPYbKSQcDzEmEPDRrDwAKQAygANXwAUXsIGc8HMIKsE0J8H4HS6HjQaK6sielKkZRsRBgUSgQjgw0SNneLmASRBWvGvClunRvimvnsTlcckG0mN0pCFpSaSQcAAPu6oSS4QikSjHVjXTJDe8APS6-WJNYUUqUWn3XzyuZPBOkpo%20MphsMAQTAYF8MA4AA9KF8oejHq04FMPPwrc53HAAkEHKRktikAB%20Dx5QpidtyOPlEVwPNgcmMuCsjncpC824WQVjGujlCOmmmrpVvg16a7huuDz4WyTfCy4dKpAqtUa95psSrkRdcy8ddbhxyMMgmPkYdIYsaHgFw-WReBxwoIA).

But since you are using typescript, you don't really need PropTypes. React itself recommends the Typescript build type-checking instead of runtime checking: https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#static-proptypes

[Ts Playground with just TS types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5&ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=10#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoSmATzCTgGEIA7GFYZpKAFVvoF44Ab3Jw4aFpmABzAFzDRY8QEZ5IpUoA2SaUmYATeQGcYUDtIA0ijQDcUmgK5IA-POYOQAIy7W4AX0UAgPIJZhNGFjYOLgARJEwUB00YJmYpaQA1eyc4QThlChCWcNSozihcuAAKMBwwI3lS9nLeOgBKeQApAGUADQA6AFFtED14fgA%20BTFQ8KFxSRl5NFT0-0raiHrCsSIYByhmat8AHn1gGwnfMSEVxel%20tGV%207V0DPzgACxQjYTu0mSPZ52Rz0AA%20YIirGasXiiWSqxkWVBAQ0JwA9OdLoo2hQ-IV0eiAIJgMD9GBGAAeVD4UPSrQEwhUajgrz0hjgJjMzGkpDgIKcrjg7i8XD5H3xlFm8BJYEqVQ6cB6A2GSFGrFyU3UCzC8BQiLkdJkDMq8yeLLZBnk%20E0ynw60lij2ByOVROTWiFVC6X4Qn19w%206ImuPIjqQlMgsDg%20jhSRlpIoQA)

Comment: propTypes and typescript types serve different purposes. You are right that defaultProps don't get deep merged by react design. I was expecting a way to mitigate the propblem.

Comment: you will need to handle it case by case, like the example I provided, or use a helper for deep merge on every component, which IMHO is a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are assigning object `config` (which require both string and number parameters) to `aConfig` which have optional number type. This simply is not possible. Notice that the `props: ContainerType & typeof ContainerDefaultProps` showing that the object infer should have both parameters which are `value and legend`.
Just Assign type to `ContainerDefaultProps` like this: And this will solve problem.

```
type a = { config: { c1: { value?: number } } };
const ContainerDefaultProps:a = { config: { c1: { value: 1 } } };
```